# How can I define a Nix environment that defaults to Python 3.5

Tags: python, nix

I have defined a the following environment in `default.nix`:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "env";
  env = buildEnv { name = name; paths = buildInputs; };
  buildInputs = [
    python35
    python35Packages.pyyaml
  ];
}
```

If I run `nix-shell`, `python` will still be the system python at `/usr/bin/python` (running on Ubuntu) while `python3` is a symlink to the Python 3.5 binary installed by Nix. Is there a way to define the environment so that `python` is pointing to the Nix Python 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution could be to add a shell hook to your environment, to define an alias from `python` to `python3`. This alias will be active only when you run `nix-shell`:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "env";
  env = buildEnv { name = name; paths = buildInputs; };
  buildInputs = [
    python35
    python35Packages.pyyaml
  ];
  # Customizable development shell setup
  shellHook = ''
    alias python='python3'
  '';
}
```

Comment: For now, this seems like the best solution, although I don't like that it would not work with scripts that use e.g. `/usr/bin/env python`. That said, there is a new pull request (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/19554) and it seems that python3 will soon be the default in Nix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `runCommand` to create a new derivation that contains only a `python` symlink.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "env";
  env = buildEnv { name = name; paths = buildInputs; };
  buildInputs = [
    (runCommand "python-alias" {} ''
      mkdir -p $out/bin
      ln -s ${python35}/bin/python3 $out/bin/python
    '')
    python35
    python35Packages.pyyaml
  ];
}
```

```
nix-shell --pure --run 'python --version'
Python 3.5.3
```